# How to know from where a function is called in Android?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to know from where a function is called in Android ??

In my application (Its a huge one, that's source code is downloaded from the internet.) a set of functions executing. I cant figure out from where they are called !

Is there any ways ??

Comment: You can use Logcat to track your codes....like Log.e("running block =","main method or something else you can write here !");

Comment: Print the stack trace.

Comment: @RohitGoswami I didn't get you ! :( Please explain..!

Comment: I tried the answer suggested by Pankaj Kumar, I tried the following code: `StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
Log.d("Stack trace",String.valueOf(stackTraceElements[1]));`
and the result on the **log** is :
`java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:591)` What does it mean ??